# ASP MVC4 Admin add user settings

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I am just learning the admin side of this in the Web Site Administration Tool, having set up a new project. I have accessed the security panel at the back end, and created an admin role, which is used to access a view through a controller filter. All standard stuff.

However when I try to log in to the front end with this user, it doesn't exist, and I have to create it afresh.

Alternatively when I create a user at the front end, and try to assign him an admin role at the back end it he also doesn't exist.

Only users created at the back end, exist at the back end and can be assigned roles

There seems to be no connection between front end users and back end users. There appears to be two separate databases one holding front end users and one back end users.

Giving a backend user admin rights doesn't seem to work from the front end.

is there some explanation on how this system work around? I have used google without help.

Comment: Congratulations on your intelligent and helpful reply.

Comment: Well, you have to admit, you basically said the same thing several times in slightly different ways.  We got it the first time.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a standard asp.net mvc 4 application, then yes.  This is to be expected.

The reason is that MVC4 by default users a different membership provider called SimpleMembership, and this provider is not compatible with the ASP.NET Configuration utility.  That configuration utility uses the old membership provider, which has entirely different tables.

Your options are:

1. don't use the web configuration utility.  Add users manually, or through a script, or maybe create your own admin pages.
2. Disable simple membership so that MVC uses the old membership system
3. do something completely different (don't use membership, use a different provider, create your own provider, etc...)

As for a separate database, yes.  If you notice, there is no membership configuration in your web.config.  Instead, the ASP.NET Congifuration utility uses the default membership configuration that's defined in your machine.config in `c:\windows\microsoft.net\framework[64]\config`.  the default location is a file located in your project directory under the App_Data directory called aspnet.mdf

EDIT:

More information about the new provider here:

http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2012/08/29/simplemembership-membership-providers-universal-providers-and-the-new-asp-net-4-5-web-forms-and-asp-net-mvc-4-templates.aspx

Also:

http://geekswithblogs.net/Aligned/archive/2012/08/30/mvc-4-authentication.aspx

Comment: Holy crap, thats depressing. Did MS mess the web config utility up, or is there a greater plan happening? Thanks for your help on this, I didn't find this information anywhere else.

Comment: @netchicken - there's nothing wrong with the web config utility.  The "issue" is that it just doesn't understand anything but a classic MembershipProvider.  SimpleMembership is an ExtendedMembershipProvider that doesn't implement many of the classic methods, thus the asp.net configuration utility won't work with it.  The reason it uses a separate database though, is because of the lack of membership configuration in web.config, but even if you configured it to use the simple provider in web.config it would throw exceptions.