# MVC 4 ASP.NET configuration

Tags: c#, security, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012, configuration

I have coded an MVC 4 application using C# in Visual Studio 2012.

If I go to Project->ASP.NET Configuration and then browse to Security, the users I create here are not linked into my application.

For example, if I create a user in the ASP.NET Configuration, the user is not a valid user to log on when I compile and run the application. Also, if I create and log on a user via the Register feature of the application, the user I create is not show in the ASP.NET Configuration.

Can I link the two together? If not, where is the ASP.NET Configuration storing the users?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope below answer will help you (From [ASP MVC4 Admin add user settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12905987/asp-mvc4-admin-add-user-settings))

If you're using a standard asp.net mvc 4 application, then yes. This is to be expected.

The reason is that MVC4 by default users a different membership provider called SimpleMembership, and this provider is not compatible with the ASP.NET Configuration utility. That configuration utility uses the old membership provider, which has entirely different tables.

Your options are:

1. don't use the web configuration utility. Add users manually, or through a script, or maybe create your own admin pages.
2. Disable simple membership so that MVC uses the old membership system
3. do something completely different (don't use membership, use a different provider, create your own provider, etc...)

As for a separate database, yes. If you notice, there is no membership configuration in your web.config. Instead, the ASP.NET Congifuration utility uses the default membership configuration that's defined in your machine.config in c:\windows\microsoft.net\framework[64]\config. the default location is a file located in your project directory under the App_Data directory called aspnet.mdf

EDIT:

More information about the new provider here:

http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2012/08/29/simplemembership-membership-providers-universal-providers-and-the-new-asp-net-4-5-web-forms-and-asp-net-mvc-4-templates.aspx

Also:

http://geekswithblogs.net/Aligned/archive/2012/08/30/mvc-4-authentication.aspx

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is there a configuration utility that can connect to the MVC 4 membership provider that is similar to the ASP.NET Configuration utility? I wish to keep with the MVC 4 membership provider.

Comment: Unfortunately there is not.